# Mount ext3 filesystem in Cygwin

Tags: mount, cygwin, ext3

I've succesfully partitioned and created an ext3 file system on my SD Card using Cygwin.
Now I need to mount that partition in Cygwin to add some files to it.

Is this somehow possible with Cygwin, or absolutely impossible?

Thanks!

Comment: Cygwin is a user space program/enviroment. There are no tools to mount filesystems

Comment: use wsl2 instead https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/access-linux-filesystems-in-windows-and-wsl-2/

Comment: In addition to @phuclv comment, Cygwin is ported bloat, wsl2 will use native elf binaries.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas you should avoid unpolite comments. Cygwin is around more than 25 years https://cygwin.com/pipermail/cygwin/2020-October/246538.html and it was built without any support from MS and worked on all version of MS Operating system by long time. It survived very well until now

Comment: @matzeri , that doesn't make it good.  Truth != Unpolite ***but I am sorry if I offended you***.  I myself used it for years because of no better technology.   It is bloated and slow compared to newer technologies.  BTW, I am a Linux c++ programmer (for over 25 years) mostly working from a Windows desktop now.  I know very well what ported code works like.

Comment: Thank you for all your comments.
I tried using wsl2, but unfortunately, wsl2 doesn't support remove media like SD Card to be mounted :(